# Using the best_in_place gem within a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I have a table that lists all users. Instead of opening each user and then editing, I want to edit certain fields within that table.

```
- @users.each do |u|
  %tr
    %td= u.name
    %td= best_in_place u, :email_flag, :type => :checkbox
```

The issue seems to be that the only param getting passed back is the checkbox field:

```
Processing by UsersController#update as
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email_flag"=>"true"}
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Why isn't the user object 'u' getting passed back?

Comment: To add another example of what I want to do, I basically want to be able to edit the last_name/country fields on the table listing in the best_in_place demo app: http://bipapp.heroku.com/

Comment: Did you yet solve your problem? Here i have an similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770064/rails-best-place-gem-for-use-in-table

Answer (score 0):

`best_in_place` is working correctly here. The entire set of attributes from that you're editing need not be transferred each time. That's what the HTTP `PUT` (or `PATCH` depending on your version of Rails) is used for -- updating attributes on existing instances of models. It's like in SQL, when you run `UPDATE users SET email='something@example.com' WHERE id=1`, you don't have to list every field every time. Only the specified columns are touched.

When you add another field for `last_name` or `country` as you said in your comment, it will work the same way.