# Rails best_place_gem for use in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I started to use the best_in_place gem, until now all worked fine. But i have my problems to get the gem work in an table:

```
 <% @ebms.each do |ebm|%> 
 <tr>
 ....
 <td><%= best_in_place ebm, :extra %></td>
```

First strange thing is that the empty column :extra is shown with -- how you can see here:

[image]

Next thing, i cant  update extra, it always displays the same --, as well when i reload!
Here is an question with the same issue: [Using the best_in_place gem within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714952/using-the-best-in-place-gem-within-a-table)

Comment: Are you sure the html for the table is correct? It almost sounds like your tags are off.

Comment: my html:http://jsfiddle.net/c6Ee3/